# CKEditor dont work in PopUp-window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, ckeditor

I use CKEditor and bPopUp jQuery plugin, if i set CKEditor just in html, without other scripts it work fine, but when i try set it into popuped window they stop working, i see just CKEditor but cant do anything, cant click for typing text, when click on buttons get errors in console. Mby somebody know is it real to fix ? I have an example here: http://kxc.lv/CKEditor_problem/

How you see, it's correctly work without popup, on start, but if click on "click me" you get popup with buggy CKEditor, and it's not cause i have two textarea with same id on a page, if i rempove first textarea without popup, it;s still dont work.
Mby somebody can help me please ?

Comment: Nobody didnt have same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In your DOM, all of your id="" must be unique. Change the second to id="editor2" and you should be fine.

Comment: No, and i left note about it in my post - " and it's not cause i have two textarea with same id on a page, if i rempove first textarea without popup, it;s still dont work."